# fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in PhpAMQP when access moved from local variable to field of object inheriting from \Thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, amqp, php-amqplib

When using a connection as a field of a class that inherits from \Thread, I receive the following error on the $this->connection->channel() call:

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /var/content-generator/PHP/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 65

If I use local varaible, everything works fine, but I receive the error as soon as I move to field calls.

Failing Code:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->run = true;
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." including", "\n";
    require_once($this->loader);
    $this->connection = GetRabbitConnection();
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." opening channel", "\n";
    $this->channel = $this->connection->channel();
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." getting queue data", "\n";

    $RedisClient = GetRedisClient();

    $ScrapeExchange = $RedisClient->get(Scrape.":".Exchange);
    $ScrapeQueue = $RedisClient->get(Scrape.":".Queue);

    $this->OutboundExchange = $RedisClient->get(Extract.":".Exchange);
    $this->OutboundRoutingKey = $RedisClient->get(Extract.":".RoutingKey);

    $RedisClient = null;

    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." consuming", "\n";

    $this->channel->basic_qos(0,1,false);
    $this->channel->basic_consume($ScrapeQueue, $ScrapeExchange, false, true, false, false, array($this, 'ProcessMessage'));

    while($this->run) {
        $this->channel->wait();
    }

    $this->channel->close();
}
```

Working Code:

```
public function run()
{
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." including", "\n";
    require_once($this->loader);
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." building connection", "\n";
    $connection = GetRabbitConnection();
    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." opening channel", "\n";
    $channel = $connection->channel();

    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." getting queue data", "\n";

    $RedisClient = GetRedisClient();

    $ScrapeExchange = $RedisClient->get(Scrape.":".Exchange);
    $ScrapeQueue = $RedisClient->get(Scrape.":".Queue);

    $this->OutboundExchange = $RedisClient->get(Extract.":".Exchange);
    $this->OutboundRoutingKey = $RedisClient->get(Extract.":".RoutingKey);

    $RedisClient = null;

    echo ' Thread-'.$this->ThreadId." consuming", "\n";

    $channel->basic_consume($ScrapeQueue, $ScrapeExchange, false, true, false, false, array($this, 'ProcessMessage'));

    while(true) {
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
}
```

What am I missing? Is there some piece of \Thread or pthreads that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are not officially supported and those objects depend on resources.

You already found the solution: use method scope variables, you can also use static (class) scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's PThreads has issues with the way it marshals object variables between instantiation and start. I ended up using an object instantiated in the `run()` function that held the object variables to do the work instead of trying to use the thread object itself, and have since had no issues.